In MockK, how can `mockkConstructor` be used to make the constructor itself thow?
I'd like to mock a constructor from a third-party library so that it always throws. Reading though Constructor mocks suggests the use of mockkConstructor, but what then? Using anyConstructed like in
mockkConstructor(SendMessageRequest::class)
every { anyConstructed<SendMessageRequest>() } throws IOException()

just gets me

Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock


I don't know if it's possible. Constructor mocking is lacking in my opinion and sometimes I end up creating a factory that does nothing but acts like a proxy towards constructor but there are no issues in mocking its methods.
